# How can I expose all functions of a member as classes own function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

There are many articles saying composition is better than inheritance in most cases (Google: composition vs inheritance).
And I tend to agree with arguments they give.

How can I expose all functions of a member as classes own function?

Detailed The question:
Hovewer I encoutered a practical where inheritance would be preferred, but its impossible due to implementation details of the base class.

Suppose I have

```
class class1 {
    constructor(options) {
        this.express = express();
    }

    my_function() {
        // ...
    }
}

let a = new class1();
```

Is there a way to make all calls work:

```
a.my_function();
a.get(...);
a.post(...);
a.<ANY_OTHER_EXPRESS_STUFF_HERE>(...);
```

My current solution

```
a.my_function();
a.express.get(...);
a.express.post(...);
a.express.<ANY_OTHER_EXPRESS_STUFF_HERE>(...);
```

What's bad with it:
- It's ugly
- I always have to go through 'express' member
- The user should know which members where (which ones are native and which come from 'base' 'class')

Restrictions:

- Can't inherit from 'express', because it's not a class.
- Can't rewrite all express functions by hand (because 1) it's a lot of work, 2) it's typescript with types' hell 3) express would evolve and add stuff, ...)
- It has to be class, I can't just inject my new members into an existing express app, because my class have bigger life cycle than contained express instance, when no express instance present all the calls should throw an error
- I write in Typescript, so the types of all Expess functions should be kept.

Comment: "*Can't inherit from 'express', because it's not a class.*" - actually you can, but it's complicated. Can you please tell us what your `class1` is supposed to do? What do you use its functions for? How does it use the express instance?

Comment: Well, in my case class1 is caching and authotization service built over express. So it offers you same as express but extends it with ability to cache and to protect pages with custom auth.

Answer (score 0):

In typescript, it may be complicated to define that your class also have the methods of express. If you want to have an example, you can look at the intl-ts package I made, especially the [Intl class](https://github.com/sveyret/intl-ts/blob/master/src/Intl.ts), defined with its own methods and a user-defined dictionary.

Comment: Can you try adding your functions as a prototype method? To your class? You should be able to get an array of methods express has using the Object.getOwnPropertyNames()  and Object.getPrototypeOf() and then loop then into your class

Comment: Well, to my opinion, yes, that's possible. In a definition, I don't think that Typescript cares if the function is prototype or not.

Comment: The Typescript need types to be explicitly set on each you call function. So if you just copy properties in javascript, the Typescript will just say "there is no such function in this class".